# Laravel Eloquent select from relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-4, eloquent

I've been trying to get the hang of Laravel. I'm using Laravel 4.
Right now I have two tables, a 'Products' table and a 'Images' table.
A product can have many images and an image belongs to a product.

So I have two models:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Image');
    }

}

class Image extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'product_images';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }

}
```

Now I'm building the 'index' page of a resource, so I do Product::all() in the controller and send this to the view.

In the view I do a foreach and loop over all products. But now I want to get an image to show with the product. But I can't seem to figure out how to get, for instance, the first image.

When I do `$product->images` I get an object of all images related to the product.

When I do `$product->images->url` I get an error (Undefined property 'url')

I've tried `$product->images->first()->url` this also gives an error (Trying to get property of non-object)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `images` property is an array-like property that you can loop through.

```
foreach ($product->images as $image) {
    echo $image->url;
}
```

Alternatively, if you only wanted the first, you can access the index.

```
$product->images[0]->url;
```

Comment: When I do this: `$product->images[0]->url`, I get `Undefined offset: 0`. When I use a foreach, it does work. Wouldn't be really nice to have to use a loop every time I just want to get one image.

Comment: Then Marko's approach should work. Sorry I wasn't able to test mine as I'm not on my development machine.

Comment: Well, I think something was wrong with my initial setup. I started an entire new project and now `$product->images[0]->url` does seem to work!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried eager-loading?

```
foreach (Product::with('images')->get() as $product)
{
    echo $product->images->first()->url;
}
```

Comment: I was trying something similar and this helped. I have a User model with role() belongsTo('Role'); and a Role model with users() hasMany('User'). I wanted to get the user with the role. This did it:

    dd(User::with('role')->find(2));

But, the with has to come first.

Comment: Thank you, it fit perfectly to what I was looking for !
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following PHP function.

```
$first_image = array_shift($product->images);
```

Then, $first_image will be one image object, and accessing the URL of the image should be easy: $first_image->ulr

Note: Haven't tested it, but should work. Let us know.